# Dynamic Objects Call relative functionality everywhere to extend a liabrary C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dynamic, extension-methods

I have different types of Objects under the same Parent class "**Control**". 
I have a ***List< Control >*** which I know can have references of ***VideoControl,HtmlControl*** etc. Which all are 'Control'. Debugging also shows that runtime cast is properly parsing them into relative **Control** and all other specific properties are present.

Now these Control objects are included in two projects, and I know using signalR I will receive a serialized list of Control objects of multiple types.

I want to call a **Draw** function on every control but in a way that my Xamarin.Android project knows how to **Draw** wach control in it's own way.

```
          foreach (Control control in listControls)
            {
                try
                {

                   control.Draw(this, myLayout);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
```

P.S. Draw is defined in an Interface so it is imposed to every control. My problem is I want to enable all projects to extend or provide functionality on their own and Draw each control with my encapsulated data.

I have searched alot and found one possible way i.e **Extension Methods** but again the problem is I have to do **explicit type cast** which will again make my code lengthy and difficult to handle.

For further assistance , I am adding my Extension methods if they can be handled without explicit type casting.

```
    public static void Render(this Control Player, object context, object container)
    {
    }

    public static void Render(this VideoPlayer Player, object context, object container)
    {

    }
    public static void Render(this HTMLControl Player, object context, object container)
    {
    }
    public static void Render(this Button Player, object context, object container)
    {
    }
```

If I do not type cast then every time my extension method for Type **Control** will run but I want to run relative method for each object.

What will be the possible way to handle this either some **partial implementation** or some **extension methods** or some other way.

Comment: If the control method and its derived classes are yours, why are you even defining the Draw/Render method as an extension method anyway? Why don't you just implement it in the class and let .NET's OOP code do its thing?

Comment: as I am writing a class library to be included in two or multiple projects and I want to enable them to call Draw on every object and provide a logic of Draw for each control. Like someone is implementing it in Xamarin Android or Windows Forms  or WPF then you just need to call Draw on each control and andle it in your own function.

Comment: Make Render method abstract method of Control class, then implement in each child class.

Comment: Is `Control` your interface, or is it a class that implements your interface? If it's the latter, do as Evk says. If not, I don't understand your question/issue.

Comment: Control is a class that implements IControl

Comment: @Technacron, then as Evk says make it abstract and make your Draw method abstract (or virtual, if you want to provide a default implementation).

Comment: My problem is I need to implement the logic of Draw/Render in separate projects.

Comment: I have tried many ways to make virtual and every time it calls the virtual function of Parent class or throws exception to implement it. But how do I implement that class partially in my project(s)

Comment: Perhaps you could include your base class code? You are using the `override` keyword in your child classes' method signatures, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should use normal OOP functionality for this. You have your control interface:

```
public interface IControl
{
    void Draw();
}
```

and an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class Control
{
    // Use abstract if you don't want to have a default
    // Draw() method in the base Control:
    public abstract void Draw();

    // Use abstract if you do want to have a default
    // Draw() method in the base Control:
    public virtual void Draw()
    {
        // basic drawing code here
    }
}
```

and then you have your derived class:

```
public class Button : Control
{
    public override void Draw()
    {
        // custom drawing code here
    }
}
```

and then finally to use it:

```
List<IControl> controls = new List<IControl>();
controls.Add(new Button());
controls.Add(new Player());
controls.Add(new Image());

foreach (IControl control in controls)
{
    control.Draw();
}
```

Comment: I need to provide Draw functionality in a separate project by including the library can i redefine or partially provide implementation of Draw . This solution is fine and will work remaining in the same assembly.

Comment: Why exactly do you think it won't work in another assembly? I don't understand.

Comment: OK, but why won't inheriting from Control, Button, etc. in and overriding Draw not work for you in another assembly? That's the part I don't understand. Entire libraries (FluentValidation, for example) are built on providing abstract classes that can be overridden in the applications using them. Why will it not be possible with your specific use case?

Comment: I need to reference  this assembly to my XamarinAndroid project . Can I provide partial implementation for Class Button in xamarin for to call Draw in xamarin way like if someone will need to call Draw in WindowsForm or WPF way it has to be implemented there not by the Class Liabrary

Comment: as my library also provides Button class implementation, in abstract way I will be in need to derive Button in XamarinAndroid or write an adapter class for it.

Comment: I'm leaving this conversation now. Just try things, you learn faster that way.